# Reorder bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

Is there any way of reordering the list of bookmarks that is shown in *bookmark-bmenu-list* (C-x r l) ?

I want to put some commonly accessed bookmarks in the top and group them by meaning.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can reorder the bookmark-list display (from `C-x r l`) in many ways, and you can easily define additional ways.

See [Sorting Bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#SortingBookmarks).  Just a flavor of what's involved:

> There are many such predefined sort orders bound to keys with the prefix `s` — use `C-h m` or `?` for more info.
>
> `s >` – Sort marked (`>`) before unmarked
>
> `s *` – Sort modified (`*`) before unmodified
>
> `s 0` – Sort by bookmark creation date/time
>
> `s b` – Sort by last buffer or file access
>
> `s d` – Sort by last bookmark access date/time
>
> `s D` – Sort flagged (`D`) before unflagged
>
> `s f d` – Sort by last local file access date/time
>
> `s f k` – Sort by local file kind: file, symlink, dir
>
> `s f n` – Sort by file name
>
> `s f s` – Sort by local file size
>
> `s f u` – Sort by last local file update (edit) date/time
>
> `s g` – Sort by Gnus thread: group, article, message.
>
> `s i` – Sort by Info manual, node, position
>
> `s k` – Sort by bookmark type (kind)
>
> `s n` – Sort by bookmark name
>
> `s t` – Sort tagged (`t`) before untagged
>
> `s v` – Sort by visit frequency